# Angular material stepper next step showing create instead of 1

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material

I am working on stepper, i want to disable next step until all filled should be filled so i made linear to true in 
html file

```
<mat-horizontal-stepper [linear]="true" #stepper>
        <mat-step [stepControl]="firstFormGroup">
          <form [formGroup]="firstFormGroup">
```

it's working fine but whenever i am going to next step, "1" becomes "cre"
on inspecting i got

[image]

i didn't user create anywhere in my code it's coming from mat-icon

Comment: try to set  [completed]="false" on mat-step to get only numbers.

Comment: Just go over looking at the entire mat-stepper mat-step  and boom it is fixed. It is likely tied up to wrong enclosing tags.

Answer (score 37):

you  can set `[completed]="false"` on `mat-step` and you will have only numbers instead of icons.

or to replace the word `"create"` with the pen icon you need to add the google material font icon link:

`<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons"rel="stylesheet">`

Comment: @ShivGaurav your welcome shiv.material should add a property for showing numbers not just icons.

Comment: [completed]="false" Doesn't allow to navigate to next step :(

Comment: Using [completed]="false" is not correct. From the Angular docs: "passing in the completed property to each of the steps, won't allow the user to continue until it becomes true. "

Comment: google material font icon link works for me, thanks

Comment: Thanks, Works it after hours of trying nonsense. <3

Answer (score 11):

add **#stepper** in mat-horizontal-stepper

```
<mat-horizontal-stepper [linear]="true" #stepper>
....
</mat-horizontal-stepper>
```

then in .ts file get that stepper

```
@ViewChild('stepper') stepper: MatHorizontalStepper;
```

and lastly, do it in afterViewInit

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
  this.stepper._getIndicatorType = () => 'number';
}
```

Comment: It should just be `@ViewChild('stepper') stepper: MatHorizontalStepper;` and it works like a charm.

Comment: From another post (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60876479/angular-9-remove-default-icon-create-on-angular-material-stepper): I did this (more type complete):
`this.stepper._getIndicatorType = (): string => STEP_STATE.NUMBER;`

Answer (score 1):

Probably you use another font-family instead default.
You can solve this issue with fix 'Material Icon' for font-family in pages that use the stepper.

```
:host /deep/ .material-icons {
  font-family: 'Material Icons' !important;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I also recently faced this issue and following code snippet with `ng-template` helped me as I was already loading Remix Icon icons in my page.

Based on the icons you are using in your web page, you can replace Remix Icon icon related code in `ng-template` and it will work for you:

```
<mat-horizontal-stepper #stepper>
            <ng-template matStepperIcon="edit"><i class="ri-edit-2-fill"></i></ng-template>
            <ng-template matStepperIcon="done"><i class="ri-checkbox-circle-fill"></i></ng-template>...</mat-horizontal-stepper>
```